# How to create a custom tab bar in Storyboard for 6 buttons?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tabbar, tabbarcontroller

I'm working on an app that will have 6 buttons on the bottom tab bar per photo below.

I've been able to successfully build all 6 storyboards and reference them to the main storyboard but I have not been able to find a solution online of how to get 6 buttons to display at once (with the screen increase in iPhone X, Apple is now allowing this per screenshot of Facebook below!).

I was hoping to accomplish this thru Storyboard alone but if not, will i have to then ditch storyboard and create a fully customized tab bar controller or is there another way?  Thanks!

[image: per this photo, Facebook iOS app routinely uses 6 buttons]
[image: storyboard for six button tab bar]